# Throttle Messages Per Second

Tags: c#, throttling

I am attempting to throttle the amount of messages I send to a SMPP SMC(server). I need to throttle them so the SMC does not throttle and drop my messages.

This is what I have tried:

```
double _client.SendSpeedLimit = 20;
if (Math.Abs(_client.SendSpeedLimit) > 1E-6 && _lastSubmit != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    check submit speed and wait for next time
    double elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastSubmit).TotalMilliseconds;
    if (elapsed < 1000f / _client.SendSpeedLimit)
    {
        int interval = Convert.ToInt32((1000f / _client.SendSpeedLimit) - elapsed);
        Thread.Sleep(interval);         
    }
}
```

and...

```
int left = (int)(start.AddSeconds(1.0 / (double)_client.SendSpeedLimit) - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds;
if (left > 0)
{
    MobileDAL.InsertError(Settings.Default.MobileConnectionString, "Throttled: " + _clientFriendlyName, "", _AccountID);
    Console.WriteLine("Throttled: " + _clientFriendlyName, "", _AccountID);
    while (left > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        left = left - 10;
    }
    start = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

But they dont seem to work as expected because I still get throttled by the service provider(SMC). 
Is there something wrong with the code? Could someone offer points of improvement?

Comment: Have you tried logging between each interval to verify you are throttling to the appropriate speed?

Comment: What are the units for `SendSpeedLimit`?

Comment: Yes I have, the methods do seem to log. However we are talking anything between 5-100 as a SendSpeedLimit(messages per second)